# Cant create std::string from one of two sources with same types

Tags: c++, string, stl, iterator

Why last line doesnt work?

```
ostringstream stream;
int f = 12345;
stream << f;
string st = stream.str();
cout << typeid(st.rbegin()).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(stream.str().rbegin()).name() << endl;
cout << string(st.rbegin(), st.rend()) << std::endl;
cout << string(stream.str().rbegin(), stream.str().rend()) << endl;
```

ir says: "String iterators incompatible", but types the same.

Comment: When adding the appropriate headers, this compiles and runs fine here, so maybe you should tell us at least the complete/real error message and what compiler you are using to try it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I don't think it's a syntax error, just a good compiler spotting a flaw in the code, see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling the `ostringstream::str()` method creates a new string object, therefore you're using iterators from two different objects.

To solve the issue, store the string in a temporary variable:

```
string temp = stream.str();
cout << string(temp.rbegin(), temp.rend()) << endl;
```

Which is what you were doing with the `st` variable already.

Answer (score 3):

`str` returns a string by value, which means the two invocations of `stream.str()` won't reference the same string in memory. And thus the iterators from them won't be compatible.